# initialize structure array and its members to zero using memset

Tags: arrays, struct, memset

I have created structure array and its members like,

```
struct hostDB {
    u_int8_t        host_id;
    u_int8_t        host_mac[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];
    unsigned char   mdvalue[1024];
    unsigned char   password[50];
};
struct hostDB structhostdb[1024];
```

I need to make structure array and its members to initialize zero. I tried with this commands but it is not working,
`memset(structhostdb,0,1024);` & `memset(structhostdb,0,sizeof(structhostdb));`  Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Their is a small problem, it should be like this:-

```
memset(structhostdb,0,sizeof(struct hostDB)*1024);
```

sizeof-> function needs the type of structure not the object of structure, so it will not be "structhostdb" but will be "struct hostDB".

To avoid confusion give different name to structure definition and to structure declaration.